# How to generate css from main.scss in yeoman angular bootstrap-saas i

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, sass, npm, yeoman

I have started a project with:

```
$ yo angular
include Twitter Bootstrap? Yes
use the SCSS version of Twitter Bootstrap with the Compass CSS Authoring Framework? Yes
$ grunt watch
```

I change the main.scss file in the app/stypes directory, I see it changed in the console, but no CSS file is generated. What is going on?

Current grunt says:

```
// Watches files for changes and runs tasks based on the changed files
watch: {
  bower: {
    files: ['bower.json'],
    tasks: ['wiredep']
  },
  js: {
    files: ['<%= yeoman.app %>/scripts/{,*/}*.js'],
    tasks: ['newer:jshint:all'],
    options: {
      livereload: '<%= connect.options.livereload %>'
    }
  },
  jsTest: {
    files: ['test/spec/{,*/}*.js'],
    tasks: ['newer:jshint:test', 'karma']
  },
  compass: {
    files: ['<%= yeoman.app %>/styles/{,*/}*.{scss,sass}'],
    tasks: ['compass:server', 'autoprefixer']
  },
  gruntfile: {
    files: ['Gruntfile.js']
  },
  livereload: {
    options: {
      livereload: '<%= connect.options.livereload %>'
    },
    files: [
      '<%= yeoman.app %>/{,*/}*.html',
      '.tmp/styles/{,*/}*.css',
      '<%= yeoman.app %>/images/{,*/}*.{png,jpg,jpeg,gif,webp,svg}'
    ]
  }
},
```

Comment: Did you config your grunt to compile your **SCSS** ?

Comment: I thought grunt is supposed to have that in place already because of yeoman?

Comment: Can you post your config here?

Comment: Its the default that comes with yo angular. Which config file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what the grunt's documentation says about compiling the style-sheets. Also note that the conversion takes place during deployment, not under **watch**.

```
sass: {
    dist: {
      files: [{
        expand: true,
        cwd: 'styles',
        src: ['*.scss'],
        dest: '../public',
        ext: '.css'
      }]
    }
  }
```

Comment: If it is not under watch, is there a way to make it so that the scss compiles while you change the scss file?

Comment: Watching scss files doesn't make any sense. The project must be deployed after compiling your assets. So put this under some default task runner.

Comment: My project is under apache, so I can load up the url anytime. That is why I want scss files to change whenever I modify it so css output is readily available.

Comment: [This](http://ryanchristiani.com/getting-started-with-grunt-and-sass/) might help you